# How to get at repeater Item from jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I've got a repeater on the page.  The repeater is actually in an .ascx.  In the repeater each item has a few things such as an Add button, and a couple of other fields.

What I am trying to the Container.DataItem but the one that relates to the Add button that was clicked.  If the user clicks the add button in the repeater list, give me reference to the Container.DataItem for that related to the button in that ItemTemplate that the user just clicked.

The add button is really just a regular HTML hyperlink wrapped around a regular HTML image.  I added an ID to the hyperlink but don't know how to really link the two and gain reference to the DataItem.

I'm all set and can fly with jQuery and do whatever client-side stuff I want.

Example of what I started:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(myUserControl.MyRepeater).
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The repeater doesn't generate any HTML of its own.  It'll only write what you tell it to write.

So what you'll have to do is somehow identify each item, preferably with unique id's in the HTML.  That way you can gain access to it through the DOM.

For example, if the rendered markup looked like this then you could actually access "item1" via jquery:

```
<div id="item1">abc</div>
<div id="item2">def</div>
```

To accomplish this you might try something like this in your ItemTemplate :

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <div id="item<%#Container.ItemIndex %>">bla</div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: right, ok then how would I link the right Container.ItemIndex with the right Add button that was clicked?  I guess I'd have to also add that kind of id to the <a href> hyperlink and then somehow check for a match in my jQuery?

Comment: Ok, then I'd probably have to add then a hidden field for any fields I'm not showing to the user in my repeater such as my container's ID which is something I'll need later on in my jQuery after the user clicks on the add button.  So as long as I have id="itemID<%#Container.ItemIndex %>" and in my hyperlinnk id="addButton<%#Container.ItemIndex %>" I can then take the ItemIndex and search for the hidden itemID by searching on itemID & Container.Index from the clicked hyperlink I guess which would be the best way unless anyone else has a better idea.

Comment: Well you might be able to come up with something involving a clever jQuery selector and click event.  It's hard for me to imagine what that something would be exactly without seeing some code.

Comment: Another thing, if each hyperlink has id="addButton<%#Container.ItemIndex %>" then if a user clicks that hyperlink, how do you know which the user clicked?  I can't see how jQuery would be able to know which hyperlink to act on.

Answer (score 1):

The `Repeater` and the `DataItem`s are server-side control which is available from the code-behind of your pages/controls. You cannot access it from client-side code (javascript).

Comment: Ok then still the question would be how would I link that button in the list with its corresponding data....this is hard to think about especially when ASP.NET creates the stupid weird IDs on everything.

Comment: WebForms creates those IDs, and it makes excellent sense in the event-driven WebForms context.

Comment: those generated IDs in asp.net suck ass. :)